# Why does " 'list' object has no attribute 'likes' "?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I am  a beginner in django. Can someone help me out in this?
Getting error like this. [ERROR IN THE PAGE IS HERE.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bbmqk.png)

**In models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    post_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=150, default="")
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sub_title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    body = models.TextField(max_length=5000)
    pub_date = models.DateField(default=now())
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='blogpost')
```

**In views.py**

```
def LikeView(request, pk):
    post = get_list_or_404(Post, post_id=request.POST.get('like_id'))
    post.likes.add(request.user)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('blogPost', args=[str(pk)]))
```

**In urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.home, name="Home"),
    path("index/", HomeView.as_view(), name="blogHome"),
    path("blogpost/<int:pk>", BlogDetailView.as_view(), name="blogPost"),
    path("edit/<int:pk>", UpdateBlog.as_view(), name="editPost"),
    path("<int:pk>/delete", DeleteBlog.as_view(), name="deletePost"),
    path("addblog/", AddBlog.as_view(), name="blogAdd"),
    path("search/", views.search, name="Search"),
    path("contact/", views.contact, name="Contact"),
    path("catmenu/", views.catmenu, name="Catmenu"),
    path("category/<str:cats>/", CategoryView, name="categoryView"),
    path("like/<int:pk>/", LikeView, name="likepost"),

] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**In html file**

```
<form action="{% url 'likepost' post.pk %}" method="POST">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <button type="submit" name="like_id", value="{{post.post_id}}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Like</button>
                </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using [get_list_or_404](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-list-or-404) which, as its name suggests, returns a list of objects matching specified condition even if there's only one matching object.

You want to use [get_object_or_404](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) instead, it returns a single object directly.